# When can golang compiler reorder commands and how sync primitives affects that?

Tags: go, concurrency, race-condition, goroutine, memory-model

I have read https://golang.org/ref/mem, but there are some parts which are still unclear to me.

For instance, in the section "Channel communication" it says: "The write to a happens before the send on c", but I don't know why that is the case. I am copying below the sample code extracted from the mentioned page for providing context.

```
var c = make(chan int, 10)
var a string

func f() {
    a = "hello, world"
    c <- 0
}

func main() {
    go f()
    <-c
    print(a)
}
```

From the point of view of a single goroutine that assertion is true, however from the point of view of another goroutine that cannot be inferred from the guarantees that the text has mentioned so far.

So my question is: Are there other guarantees which are not explicitly stated in this document? For instance, can we say that given some sync primitive such as sending on a channel, ensures that commands placed before it, will not be moved after it by the compiler? What about the commands which comes after it, can we say that they will not be placed before the sync primitive?

What about the operations offered in the atomic package? Do they provide the same guarantees as channels operations?

Comment: "Are there other guarantees which are not explicitly stated in this document" no. The spec and the memory model state exactly what is expected from the language.

Answer (score 2):

> can we say that given some sync primitive such as sending on a channel, ensures that commands placed before it, will not be moved after it by the compiler?

That is exactly what the memory model says. When you look at a single goroutine, the execution order can be rearranged so that effects of write operations are visible in the order they appear in the execution. So if you set `a=1` at some point and read `a` later, the compiler knows not to move the write operation ahead of the read. For multiple goroutines, channels and locks are the synchronization points, so anything that happened before a channel/lock operation is visible to other goroutines once the synchronization point is reached. The compiler will not move code around so that a write operation crosses the synchronization boundary.

There are guarantees satisfied by the sync/atomic operations as well, and there have been discussions on whether to add them to the memory model. They are not explicitly stated at the moment. There is an open issue about it:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5045